# How to include SNI within SSL handshake when creating a new Web Service Client in NetBeans?

Tags: java, ssl, netbeans, wsdl, sni

I’m trying to create a new Web Service Client in my Java Application within NetBeans 8.2.  After Specifying my WSDL URL within the New Web Service Client Wizard and click Finish, I get an Error stating:

“Problem with Downloading wsdl or schema file.  Check the URL, proxy settings or whether the server is running. URL: https://{server_name}/{service_name}.svc?wsdl”

The service is running on IIS8.5 with SNI enabled.  Looking at the Handshake Protocol: Client Hello within Wireshark, I see that the Extension: server_name is missing, which is required for a successful handshake.

I cannot create a new SOAP project in SoapUI 5.3.0 either as it also does not include the server_name in the Handshake.
My JDK and JRE version is 1.8.0_111.

Is there a way to get Netbeans to include the required SNI in the Client Hello Handshake when creating a new Web Service Client?

Here is the Wireshark output for the Secure Sockets Layer generated by NetBeans.

Secure Sockets Layer

```
SSL Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 233
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 229
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random
        Session ID Length: 0
        Cipher Suites Length: 100
        Cipher Suites (50 suites)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
        Extensions Length: 88
        Extension: elliptic_curves
        Extension: ec_point_formats
        Extension: signature_algorithms
```